# Is there a way to change the Windows ALT+Print Screen command to produce a smaller file than BitMap - perhaps jpg or png?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, screen-capture

Looking for a mechanism - with minimal/no install of 3rd party software so that the ALT + Printscreen keyboard command produces a reasonably sized image when pasted into an email.

Currently on Windows XP if I perform an ALT Print Screen and paste into an outlook or groupwise email message - the email message becomes a 4 Megabyte email - which is not fun to download to a phone.

Comment: Any reason you can't use mspaint to crop/resize/change formats?

Comment: Yes - I can.  But is more difficult to convince others - who often send screenshots via email to highlight a bug or question.  Sending the instructions to first convert to PNG in MSPaint or install snagit, or install a browser plugin etc... just makes folks who hate computers hate them more.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest method with no autohotkey or 3rd party software is to open MS Paint after ALT+PRINT SCREEN, then CTRL+V to paste the image in and then CTRL+S to open the save dialog, where you can select another format such as JPEG.

Answer (score 3):

The only guaranteed way to do this would be to save the screen shot as a png file and then send that with the e-mail as an attachment.

By embedding the image in the e-mail you are forcing it to be uncompressed.